# Weird "jump" when typing in styled input field in IE10

Tags: css, input, internet-explorer-10, html5-kickstart

I've a website based on Html KickStart and I notice an annoying problem in IE10.

The issue: when you open the web page, the text in the input field is aligned against the left hand side of the field. When you put the focus on it, and start typing, the text jumps to the right (where it is supposed to be, as you can see in other browsers). When the field looses the focus, the text jumps left again, against the side once more. The input field in question is styled.

The problem is clearly visible on the Html KickStart demo site:
http://www.99lime.com/elements/

Here you can also find the css code files etc.

I don't seem to be able to find the cause of this behaviour. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this css property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

`direction` effects the css declaration being used known as `text-align:start`

which isn't supported by IE 10

Comment: Ok, I checked it, but as far as I can see this css property is not used in styling the input by KickStart?